# page header in latex

Tags: header-footer, lyx

I would like to create the following at the top of each page of my latex document.

[image]

Here is my MWE.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside,english,pdfprintscaling=none]{article}
 \usepackage{color}
 \definecolor{shadecolor}{rgb}{0.667969, 0.0234375, 0.496094}

 \begin{document}
 
  \begin{flushright}
   {\fboxsep 1pt\framebox[1\textwidth][l]{%
 \begin{minipage}[b][1\totalheight][c]{4.1cm}%
 \begin{shaded}%
 \begin{flushright}
 \textsf{\textbf{\textcolor{white}{\large{}Year Twelve}}}
 \par\end{flushright}\end{shaded}%
 \end{minipage}}}
 \par\end{flushright}
\end{document}
```

Here is my output:

[image]

Comment: Wouldn't be enough to change the height of minipage? Could you explain what is the problem in more detail?

Comment: your example doesn't compile without errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of `fancyhrd` and `nicematrix`:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{shadecolor}{rgb}{0.667969, 0.0234375, 0.496094}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{cellspace}

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyhead{%
\NiceMatrixOptions{cell-space-top-limit = 3pt}
  \begin{NiceTabular}[colortbl-like]{wr{4.5cm}m{\dimexpr\textwidth-4.5cm-4\tabcolsep-3\arrayrulewidth}}[hvlines]
  \cellcolor{shadecolor}\Large\color{white}\bfseries\sffamily Year Twelve & \\ 
  \end{NiceTabular}
  }

\pagestyle{fancy}
\setlength{\headheight}{36pt}

\usepackage{lipsum} % for dummy text. Do not use in real document.
\begin{document}
 
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. It works great.